# How to find data between two values

Tags: string, matlab, user-interface, matrix

I am trying to find the data between two values. I am using this code in a GUI programme, the starting_value and ending_value which you can see in the code below are selected from 2 listboxes in a previous part of the code.

```
% --- Executes on button press in CalculateIntensity.
function CalculateIntensity_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to CalculateIntensity (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% Trapz function
starting_value = getappdata(0,'StartValue');
ending_value = getappdata(0,'EndValue');
StartingValue = str2mat(starting_value)
EndingValue = str2mat(ending_value)
A = getappdata(0,'XYarray')
data_found = A(A(:,[1,2]) > StartingValue & A(:,[1,2]) < EndingValue)
```

I found help on:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8556-how-to-find-vector-elements-between-two-values-efficiently
However the

```
data_found = A(A(:,[1,2]) > StartingValue & A(:,[1,2]) < EndingValue)
```

part of the code wont work for me, I think starting_value and ending_value are strings so I tried converting it to a matrix but I get the error:
Error using  <
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in MichelleLaycockGUImainwindow>CalculateIntensity_Callback (line 119)
data_found = A(A(:,[1,2]) > StartingValue & A(:,[1,2]) < EndingValue)

an example of data used is:
A =

1.0e+03 *

```
0.1660    1.1570
0.1664    0.4650
0.1668         0
0.1672    1.0200
0.1676    1.0110
0.1680    1.0200
0.1684    1.0640
0.1688    1.1100
0.1692    1.0370
0.1696    1.0050
0.1700    1.0750
0.1704    1.0850
0.1708    1.1310
0.1712    1.0630
0.1716    1.0370
0.1719    1.1070
0.1724    1.1450
```

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated as it's all I need to complete my work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Q: How to use a while loop to get data between values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539967/q-how-to-use-a-while-loop-to-get-data-between-values)

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question?

Comment: It differs in the approach I am taking this time I'm not using a loop as I thought this may be more simple @Dan

Comment: If your error is when you are converting from a string, then please include that section of the code!

Comment: I suspect `StartingValue` and `EndingValue` aren't scalars. Could you find info on them?

Comment: It is included already @dan

Comment: Yes @Divakar if I dont suppress StartingValue and EndingValue they equal the value that I have selected. Could it be something to do with having two coloums of data?

Comment: @user3580436 I am still not clear, are they scalars?

Comment: Sorry @Divakar you are right StartingValue and EndingValue are not scalars. Is there a way you know I could make them scalars?

Comment: Could you give us output of these commands - `whos StartingValue` and `whos EndingValue`?

Comment: Name: StartingValue Size: 1x2 Bytes: 16 Class:double  Attributes:

                                 

  Name             Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

        1x19               38  char

Comment: Sorry @Divakar this may be clearer than the last comment. Name: StartingValue Size: 1x2 Bytes: 16 Class:double  Attributes:
Name:EndingValue  Size: 1x19 Bytes:38 Class:char  Attributes

Comment: Try this - `A(bsxfun(@gt,A(:,[1,2]),StartingValue) & bsxfun(@lt,A(:,[1,2]),EndingValue))`

Comment: @Divakar that did not work either. I got the error: Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Comment: Different sized StartingValue and EndingValue  doesn't make sense to me really.

Comment: The problem is the `EndingValue`. You have a 1x19 char vector there it makes no sense that the type of `StartingValue` is a double and `EndingValue` is a string. Are you sure that there are no other error?

Comment: That was my fault I had changed StartingValue to str2num and forgot to change EndingValue so now whos StartingValue and whos EndingValue produces. Name:StartingValue Size: 1x2 Bytes:16 Class: double  Attributes:
Name:EndingValue Size:1x2 Bytes:16 Class: double  Attributes. When I use the piece of code 'A(bsxfun(@gt,A(:,[1,2]),StartingValue) & bsxfun(@lt,A(:,[1,2]),EndingValue))' it produces the correct data from the first column but then gives me data from before and after I selected in the second column. @Divakar

Comment: @Divakar I think that piece of code may be giving me all the data less than EndingValue and greater than the StartingValue in the second column as the numbers increase and decrease rather than just increasing like column 1.

Comment: @user3580436 The code provided by Divakar works perfectly for me. The only side effect is that the result is provided as a column vector. This can easily be reshaped as `reshape(theAns,numel(theAns)/2,2)`. If you have got any else it would most likely be for some other reason

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I found a different way to get what I want by using [~,indx1]=ismember(StartingValue,A,'rows') to find the row number and extract the data that way! Thanks again.

Comment: @user3580436 You can post everything as an answer and accept it, so that this doesn't stay as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the values in my data vary rather than just decreasing or increasing the greater than or equal to method I was originally trying to use did not work. So rather than using the loop to get the data between the two points selected I went with a different method.

I use`[~,indx1]=ismember(StartingValue,A,'rows')` this finds the row number of the selected data and then I use this information to extract the data between and including the selected data.
Here is the full code I used to do this:

```
starting_value = getappdata(0,'StartValue');
ending_value = getappdata(0,'EndValue');
StartingValue = str2num(starting_value);
EndingValue = str2num(ending_value);

A = getappdata(0,'XYarray');
[~,indx1]=ismember(StartingValue,A,'rows');
[~,indx2]=ismember(EndingValue,A,'rows');
arrayfortrapz = A(indx1:indx2,1:2); %array of data including and between selected data
```

I hope this of some help to anybody that may run into a similar issue.